# "Request Timed Out" Using tracert

Tags: wireless-networking

I've been having this problem for the past year and I have no idea why. I reset my modem, router, made my connection wired, none of which have helped. I can load pages and watch videos easily, but when I play certain games online that need a stable internet connection, I get "Connection Lost" every time (I play RuneScape). This happens on all websites. I am using a WiFi connection. Router: D-Link. Modem: Arris. ISP: Videotron (Live in Canada). This happens When I do tracert I get the following: (ALWAYS happens at the second hop, then sometimes afterwards)

[image: https://gyazo.com/c9d678ce8f95477d01d791752339167f]

Answer (score 0):

`Traceroute` sends multiple ICMP requests much like `ping`. Except that the length of time the request takes is measured three times instead of four times.

A request timed out may or may not be indicative of a connectivity issue. In your case where it's on the second hop only and all three requests time out it usually means that the device that is being pinged on at the hop has its firewall configured to reject ICMP packets rather than that you have a connectivity issue. The rest of the tracert looks ok and completes successfully.

I know that online games use ICMP packets, but unless your ISP is blocking them for some reason I don't see why it would cause your problem. It's something you should take up with your ISP. The first hop is your machine to the router, the second hop is from your router to your ISP, so that's where to look for assistance.

If you administer your own router than check that ICMP requests are not being blocked on it, these are typically blocked to prevent `denial of service` attacks.